# Merging arrays and keeping empty values in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, merge

I am trying to get back into PHP, but am really struggling with this.
I am building a booking system for booking a tennis court. The user can see the times and whether the court is booked or not at the specific time.
The bookings are stored in a MySQL table with just two columns: a datetime and the id of the user who booked it.
I am able to retrieve the data like this:

```
    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT bookingDate, booked_by FROM Court1 WHERE bookingDate LIKE ?');

    $sth->execute(array("%$time%"));

    // Array to hold the bookings
    $getCourt1 = array();

    //Getting the data from db
    while($r=$sth->fetch()){

            $courtData[0]   = substr($r['bookingDate'], 10, 12);
            $courtData[1]   = $r['booked_by'];

            array_push($getCourt1, $courtData);
    }
```

My idea was to "merge" the retrieved data with a predefined array holding the times possible to book the court.

```
    $base = array(array('08:00:00',''), array('09:00:00', ''), array('10:00:00', ''), array('11:00:00', ''), array('12:00:00', ''), array('13:00:00', ''), array('14:00:00', ''), array('15:00:00', ''), array('16:00:00', ''), array('17:00:00', ''), array('18:00:00', ''), array('19:00:00', ''), array('20:00:00', ''));
```

The reason for this is that I need to show the times available for booking even when they haven't been booked.
I have tried several approaches, but this one is the closest I have gotten:

```
    $aCourt1 = array_replace($base, $getCourt1);
```

The merged array is returned to a controller, which builds the html and then passes it to a view as variable like this:

```
    $aCourt1 = $booking->showBookings($time);
    $court1 = '
            <tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[0][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[0][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[0][1].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[1][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[1][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[1][1].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[2][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[2][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[2][1].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[3][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[3][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[3][1].'</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[4][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[4][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[4][1].'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="courtTime">'.$aCourt1[5][0].'</td>
                <td class="courtBook '.$aCourt1[5][1].'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$aCourt1[5][1].'</td>
            </tr>';
```

The table is showing just fine, but the entries for the specific day are shown first and then the rest of the times appear chronological after that.
I have tried most array functions and to make it work through a loop, but so far I have been unsuccessful. I must be off somewhere, but not sure where, so hopefully someone can advice me. Thanks in advance.
PS: I plan to use a boolean to check if the timeslot is booked or not, but the problem is that I am trying to avoid to create a full time table for every day and just use one table indexed by datetime for each court. Maybe there is a better way to have a default table rather than merging arrays??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the time as key to the array, this way you can pre-fill your defaults and overwrite necessary entries using the query:

```
$sth = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT bookingDate, booked_by FROM Court1 WHERE bookingDate LIKE ?');

$sth->execute(array("%$time%"));

// Set defaults
$courtData = array('08:00:00' => '', '09:00:00' =>  '', '10:00:00' =>  '', '11:00:00' =>  '', '12:00:00' =>  '', '13:00:00' =>  '', '14:00:00' =>  '', '15:00:00' =>  '', '16:00:00' =>  '', '17:00:00' =>  '', '18:00:00' =>  '', '19:00:00' =>  '', '20:00:00' =>  '');

//Getting the data from db
while($r=$sth->fetch()){
    $timestamp = strtotime($r['bookingDate'];
    $time = date("H:i:s", $timestamp);
    $courtData[$time] = $r['booked_by'];
}
```

And in your controller:

```
$aCourt1 = $booking->showBookings($time);
$court1 = '';
foreach($aCourt1 as $time => $booker)
{
    $court1 .= '<tr>';
    $court1 .= ' <td class="courtTime">'.$time.'</td>';
    $court1 .= ' <td class="courtBook '.$booker.'" data-target="#confirmBooking">'.$booker.'</td>';
    $court1 .= '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much! This is very close to my original approach, but I must have been messing up the syntax, cos I couldn't get it to work. Once again, thank you so much. It makes perfect sense once you see it :)